# Perplexed about OpenCL global memory on system with multiple GPUs

Tags: opencl

I have a machine with 2 GPUs (two Intel Arc A770 cards). When I run clinfo, each GPU reports maximum memory to be 12 GB and in my program I have separate contexts for each device. But when I try to allocate memory, it seems allocating the context of one device effects the other's available memory.

In other words, I am only able to allocate a total of 12 GB (about 6GB one one device and 6 GB on another).

Here are snippets of code where I create the separate contexts:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < ngpus; i++) {
    contexts[i] = clCreateContext(properties, 1, &devices[i], contextCallback, NULL, &err);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not create GPU context: %d\n", err);
      return err;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "%d: OpenCL context created successfully\n", 0);
```

And here is my memory allocation code:

```
  int ngpus, i, j;
  cl_int err;
  size_t asize, atotal;
  cl_mem mem;

  err = 0;
  atotal = 0;
  asize = 512 * 1024 * 1024L;
  for (i = 0; i < 140 && err == 0; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ngpus && err == 0; j++) {
      mem = clCreateBuffer(contexts[j], CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, asize, NULL, &err);
      if (err != CL_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nCould not create memory, err %d\n", err);
        break;
      }
      atotal += asize;
    }
    if (err == 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%d:%d: Allocated %zd MB (%zd MB total) successfully\r", j, i, asize / (1024 * 1024), atotal / (1024 * 1024));
    }
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "\nError code %d\n", err);
```

And the results of running the above code:

```
Platform profile: FULL_PROFILE
Platform version: OpenCL 3.0
Name: Intel(R) OpenCL HD Graphics
Found 2 devices
0: OpenCL context created successfully
0: Program loaded successfully
0: OpenCL context created successfully
0: Program loaded successfully
OpenCL kernels built successfully
2:126: Allocated 512 MB (130048 MB total) successfully
Could not create memory, err -6

Error code -6
```

I don't understand why I am getting CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY when I am allocating memory on the devices. Also, why do I run out after 13 GB allocation (presumably about 6 GB per device)?

Thanks in advance.

I am expecting that I will be able to allocate close to 12 GB on each device (totaling 24 GB).

Comment: What exactly are the GPUs in this system? They might be set up to share memory with the system - this is particularly common for integrated GPUs.

Comment: Do you have only 16GB on your Host system? OpenCL typically allocates a host buffer, not just on the device.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 GPUs in your system reported as 2 OpenCL devices are actually the same 1 GPU (some Intel HD Graphics integrated GPU). It is just wrongly reported duplicate.

2 possibilities what could be wrong:

1. You actually have 2 OpenCL devices available (Intel CPU and Intel iGPU), but you wrongly place the iGPU twice in your devices list as `devices[0]` and `devices[1]`. Technically you can have the same device multiple times in a Context, but of course if you allocate memory on one of them, it will be occupied on the other one as well because it's the same device.
2. Faulty driver installation. Maybe a driver update did not clear up the old version. A fresh driver install after whipe with Display Driver Uninstaller could help.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have 2 Intel Arc A770 cards in my system. The reporting of the 2 GPUs is correct.

I can't comment - don't have enough reputation points. I am going edit my OP as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).